# Hibernate (Panache) Repository Best Practices

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus, repository-pattern

I am currently working on a system where we manage a significant number of customers and their associated end-customers. Typically, each of our customers has 1-10K end-customers, but this number can go up to 1 million in some extreme cases.

I have an EndCustomerEntity class that includes two lazy @OneToMany relationships. Due to performance considerations, each EndCustomerEntity can have a maximum of 30 fields and labels. The logic for adding and updating these fields and labels is currently encapsulated directly within the EndCustomerEntity. However, this approach has resulted in a complex and lengthy entity class.

While the existing design provides a nice encapsulation, the complexity and size of the EndCustomerEntity makes it challenging to handle. In addition, I need to be notified when a field or label is added, updated, or deleted. To achieve this with the current structure, I would presumably need to use Hibernate-specific features like annotation-based event listeners, interceptors, or other JPA annotations, but I am not sure if this is the best path.

Given these challenges, I am exploring several alternatives:

1. Retain the current entity but incorporate event listeners or interceptors for change notifications.
2. Maintain the @OneToMany lists within the EndCustomerEntity, but delegate the management of these lists to a dedicated service.
3. Remove the @OneToMany lists from EndCustomerEntity and combine the three entities in the business domain.
4. Move the management of the @OneToMany lists into static Mappers/Factories that are invoked from the entity, while maintaining listeners/interceptors for change notifications.
5. Similar to option 4, but have the Mappers/Factories called from an EndCustomer ORM Service/Repository.

Recently, I've considered shifting the logic into the repository. This change would ensure atomicity as all ORM-related changes to the EndCustomerEntity would go through the repository. To keep the code in the repository minimal, I could calculate the add/remove/update operations for fields and labels in a Factory.

Here is an example of this idea:

```
public class EndCustomerRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<EndCustomerEntity, UUID> {
    private final EndCustomerFieldRepository endCustomerFieldRepository;
    private final EndCustomerLabelRepository endCustomerLabelRepository;

    private EndCustomerEntity updateEntity(EndCustomerEntity existingEntity, EndCustomer updatedEndCustomer) {
        EndCustomerFieldUpdate endCustomerFieldUpdate = EndCustomerFieldUpdateFactory.updateEndCustomerFields(existingEntity.id, existingEntity.endCustomerFields, updatedEndCustomer.endCustomerFields());

        removeFields(endCustomerFieldUpdate.fieldsToRemove());
        updateFields(endCustomerFieldUpdate.fieldsToUpdate());
        addFields(endCustomerFieldUpdate.fieldsToAdd());

        return existingEntity.update(updatedEndCustomer.firstName(), updatedEndCustomer.email(), updatedEndCustomer.status());
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I've also considered having the repository delegate the update of field and label lists to ORM-related services (or DAOs?). Here's a sketch of this idea:

```
public class EndCustomerRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<EndCustomerEntity, UUID> {
    private final FieldOrmService fieldOrmService;
    private final LabelOrmService labelOrmService;

    public EndCustomerRepository(FieldOrmService fieldOrmService, LabelOrmService labelOrmService) {
        this.fieldOrmService = fieldOrmService;
        this.labelOrmService = labelOrmService;
    }

    public EndCustomerEntity updateEntity(EndCustomerEntity existingEntity, EndCustomer updatedEndCustomer) {
        fieldOrmService.updateFields(existingEntity.id, existingEntity.endCustomerFields, updatedEndCustomer.endCustomerFields());
        labelOrmService.updateLabels(existingEntity.id, existingEntity.endCustomerLabels, updatedEndCustomer.endCustomerLabels());
        
        return existingEntity.update(updatedEndCustomer.firstName(), updatedEndCustomer.email(), updatedEndCustomer.status());
    }
}
```

Given these considerations, what would you recommend as the best practice in this scenario? I am open to any suggestions or insights that you might have!

Thanks for your help!